# check hash value within an array

Tags: arrays, ruby, ruby-hash

I have an array (array1) of hashes that looks like this :

```
array1 = [
           {:ID=>"1", :value=>"abc"},
           {:ID=>"2", :value=>"def"}
         ]
```

I can loop over each hash and check each hash value manually:

```
array1.each do |h|
  if h.has_value?("def")
    #do something
  end
end
```

Is there a way to check if the hash value "abc" exists within a hash inside the array without having to iterate over the array?

Comment: Yes, don't use an array. It takes away the `O(1)` point of lookup for hash tables. Just use a JS Object literal for this.

Comment: Where does `array1` come from, how is it generated? Is it possible to change the structure (for example to an hash) at the origin of `array1`?

Comment: Do you consider `"1"` to be a value inside a hash of your array?

Comment: yes, by definition "1" and "abc" are values of the hash. Where "ID" and "value" are keys.

Answer (score 2):

`find` method is the most concise way with an array.

```
array1.find { |item| item[:value] == 'abc' }
```

Anyway, if you can start directly with an hash is better but if you have to switch to an hash from an array to have the O(1) lookup, it will probably be slower anyway.

Answer (score 2):

use `any?` instead of each, it breaks in early stage if found, best case O(1) and worst case O(n)

```
word = "def"
is_present = array1.any? { |h| h.has_value?(word) }
```

is_present is `true` if `word` is found in hash otherwise `false`

Comment: But this iterates over the array, which the OP doesn't want to do and is still `O(n)`.

Comment: yes, you have to iterate ultimately, but ruby has any? which ease our work, how will u find element in array by iterating right.

Comment: @SpencerWieczorek There is no avoiding iteration, however `any?` will stop processing at the first `true` value, avoiding a full array scan.

Comment: @MarkThomas You could certainly avoid iteration, OP is asking for a solution to an XY Problem.

Comment: @SpencerWieczorek Agreed. An array is not the best starting point.

Comment: @MarkThomas, I agree that an array is ideal to start with. What would you recommend? storing everything in a hash as opposed to array?

Comment: @danynl if the typical use case is to check for the existence of a value, then the values you are using should actually be the keys of a hash.

Answer (score 1):

One way or another, you can't avoid iterating over the array. Here's one way.

```
array1.flat_map(&:values).include?("def")
  #=> true
```

Note

```
array1.flat_map(&:values)
  #=> ["1", "abc", "2", "def"]
```

Comment: From the question, I don't know if `"1"` and `"2"` should be here.

Answer (score 0):

You obviously have to iterate at least once over the elements of your array.

If you do this often, you should use another data format:

```
array1 = [
  { ID: '1', value: 'abc' },
  { ID: '2', value: 'def' },
  { ID: '3', value: 'abc' }
]

lookup_table = array1.each_with_object(Hash.new { |h, k| h[k] = [] }) do |hash, table|
  table[hash[:value]] << hash[:ID]
end

p lookup_table
# {"abc"=>["1", "3"], "def"=>["2"]}
p lookup_table['abc']
# ["1", "3"]
```

As a bonus, it gives you all the `ID`s for which this value is found, and it gives it fast.

If you just want to know if there's a value somewhere in your hashes, you could use a `Set`:

```
require 'set'
all_values = Set.new(array1.map{|h| h[:value]})
p all_values.include? 'abc'
# true
p all_values.include? 'xyz'
# false
```

Again, the lookup will be much faster than with an array of hashes.